# Swift Map Observable<T> to Observable<T>

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

Im confused about converting RxSwift Observable<T> to Observable<T>

I have function for networking like this:

```
func createOrder(request: AcquirebatchOrder) -> Observable<AcquirebatchOrderResult> {
    //Do networking stuff and will return with Observable<AcquirebatchOrderResult>
}
```

And I can call that function like this:

```
transferService.createOrder(request: request)
```

And I need to convert Observable<AcquirebatchOrderResult> to Observable<TransferSubmitResult> because I don't want to duplicate observeResultForShowUI with different parameter.
I have tried this but failed:

```
let observableResult = transferService.createOrder(request: request).map {
acquirebatchOrderResult -> Observable<TransferSubmitResult> in
            let transferSubmitResult = TransferSubmitResult()
            //Doing something to convert data from acquirebatchOrderResult to transferSubmitResult
            Observable.just(transferSubmitResult)
}

observeResultForShowUI(result: observableResult)

private func observeResultForShowUI(result: Observable<TransferSubmitResult>) {
   result.subscribe { [weak self] (result: TransferSubmitResult) in
        //Do something with data
   } onError: { (error: Error) in
        //Handle error
   }
}
```

The error shown when passing observableResult to function observeResultForShowUI

> Cannot convert value of type 'Observable<Observable<TransferSubmitResult>>' to expected argument type 'Observable<TransferSubmitResult>'

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're needlessly nesting things.

To go from `Observable<A>` to an `Observable<B>` using `map`, you need to give it a function of type `(A) -> B`.

What you did was give it a function from `(AcquirebatchOrderResult) -> Observable<TransferSubmitResult>` (so your "B" is `Observable<TransferSubmitResult>`). Thus your result ended up as `Observable<<Observable<TransferSubmitResult>>`

All you need is:

```swift
let observableResult = transferService
    .createOrder(request: request)
    .map { _ in TransferSubmitResult() }
```

Although it's odd that your `TransferSubmitResult` doesn't use the `acquirebatchOrderResult` at all.

Comment: Hey its working hehe thank you.. btw TransferSubmitResult use acquirebatchOrderResult but I dont show it in code example since its just data matter..